# Getting NULL as response to CURL POST request in php

Tags: php

```
<?php
$url = 'https://leetcode.com/graphql';
$query = array("operationName"=>"questionData","variables"=>array("titleSlug"=>'jump-game'),"query"=>"query questionData(\$titleSlug: String!) {\n  question(titleSlug: \$titleSlug) {\n    questionId\n    questionFrontendId\n  difficulty\n  boundTopicId\n    title\n    titleSlug\n    content\n  categoryTitle\n  translatedTitle\n    translatedContent\n topicTags{name slug }\n }\n}\n");
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,array('content-type'=>'application/json'));
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,json_encode($query));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
$resp=curl_exec($ch);
var_dump($resp);
curl_close($ch);
?>
```

getting null value response to the post request every time. Can anyone guide me as to what i am doing wrong? Code works with javascript's fetch API but fails with PHP . I am new to PHP

Comment: I ran your code, but did not get `null` as a response. Instead I got a long error message (403 Forbidden) with explanation that _"... this HTTPS site requires a “Referer header” to be sent by your Web browser, but none was sent. This ... "_ (more text is returne, but cropped from this comment

Comment: Strange i am getting NULL dunno why. I put curl_error($ch) too but it gives no error. Any idea why this code works using fetch api?

Comment: You can also try to call `curl_getinfo()` (https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-getinfo.php) after your `curl_exec` call.